# PHP: How can $this variable inside one class be object of another one?

Tags: php, oop, this, static-methods

Here is an example:

```
class Test {

    public function TestMethod() {

        print_r($this); // Gives me "Test1 Object ( )"

    }
}

class Test1 {

    public function Test1Method() {

        Test::TestMethod();

    }
}

$test1 = new Test1;
$test1->Test1Method();
```

I find this strange. Can anyone please explain to me why it happens?

Comment: I asked a very similar (Not a dupe) question. The responses were very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516355/calling-static-method-from-class-bwhich-extends-class-a-of-class-a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php:

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available
>   when a method is called from within an
>   object context. `$this` is a reference
>   to the calling object (usually the
>   object to which the method belongs,
>   but possibly another object, if the
>   method is called statically from the
>   context of a secondary object).

This doesn't necessarily make a lot of sense, though, and will invoke a warning if `E_STRICT` is enabled.

Comment: It would make sense if `Test1` were a subclass of `Test`; maybe it's just a cheap way of recreating the `this` behaviour found in languages that were designed for OOP from the start.

Comment: What is the best way to check if `$this` references to current class? I need it to check if method was called staticly or from object. I guess it's something like `if ( $this instanceof __CLASS__ ) {}`. Am I right?

Comment: @SaltLake: I don't know.  But personally, I would enable `E_STRICT` to prevent this sort of hackery!  It can only lead to pain in the long-run.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You are calling a "non static" method using a static function call, php then tries to find a "$this" and the last real "$this" was the one in Test1.

If you turn on E_STRICT error reporting it will complain about that.

Answer (score 0):

Is [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) if I'm not mistaking, which could be as is late Friday.