# scope of $this is funked in PHP is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: php, oop

I have this code:

```
    class a(){
      function b(){
         if(isset($this){
            echo 'instance! ';
            echo get_class($this);
         }else{
            echo 'static';
         }
      }
    }


class C{
  public function test(){
      a::b();
  }
}

$CC=new C;
$CC->test();
```

This will echo

> instance C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this

Comment: I think it's a hybrid between a bug and a feature... There's a dupe about this, maybe I can find it

Comment: @md03514 your point being? Itay understands the difference between the two. Look at the code (edit: Ah, there are some in-depth explanations there that may explain things.)

Comment: I had a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516355/calling-static-method-from-class-bwhich-extends-class-a-of-class-a. From Ulf: "If you call the static method bound to the other object, the method is executed in the context of the current object. Which allows access to the $this-object."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. **$this is a reference to the calling object** (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

So definitely, it's a feature, it's by design, and it's not a bug.

Comment: LOL - seems to me like a bug they turned into a feature as it was too complex to fix. This brakes the encapsulation concept.

Comment: I consider it a bug. I can't image it's by design, because it's very strange.